# WEKA difference between output of J48 and ID3 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, weka, id3

I have a data set which I am classifying in `WEKA` using `J48` and `ID3` algorithm. The output of `J48` algorithm is:

```
Correctly Classified Instances          73               92.4051 %

Incorrectly Classified Instances         6                7.5949 %

Kappa statistic                          0.8958

Mean absolute error                      0.061 

Root mean squared error                  0.1746

Relative absolute error                 16.7504 %

Root relative squared error             40.9571 %

Total Number of Instances               79
```

and the output using ID3 is:

```
Correctly Classified Instances          79              100      %

Incorrectly Classified Instances         0                0      %

Kappa statistic                          1     

Mean absolute error                      0     

Root mean squared error                  0     

Relative absolute error                  0      %

Root relative squared error              0      %

Total Number of Instances               79
```

My question is, if `J48` is an extension of `ID3` and is newer compared to it, how come `ID3` is giving a better result than `J48`?

Comment: This would be a better question for stats.stackexchange.com. Briefly, the model's accuracy when run on the training set is not a good measure of its actual quality. When run on data that wasn't in the training set, the J48 model is likely to exhibit higher accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The J48 model is more accurate in the quality in the process, based in *C4.5 is an extension of ID3 that accounts for unavailable values, continuous attribute value ranges, pruning of decision trees, rule derivation, and so on.* The result in this case is only reflect of the kind of your data set you used. The ID3 could be implemented when you need more faster/simpler result without taking into account all those additional factors in the J48 consider. Take a Look into pruning decision tree and deriving rule sets [HERE](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/cis587/readings/id3-c45.html)
In the web are a lot of resource in the theme about these comparatives results its more important to learn to identified in which case we apply the different classifier once we know how each one work[(1)](http://www.mecs-press.org/ijmecs/ijmecs-v5-n5/IJMECS-V5-N5-3.pdf)

Comment: so, it isn't incorrect to get id3 algorithm more accurate than j48 in some cases right?

Comment: Not more accurate, its a "simpler" result(because doesnt consider all the points above in the J48). Neither are wrong, you could say that the ID3 is more like and generalized overview of the DATA and J48 is  more nitpicky in the way it classify the same DATA

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees are more likely to face problem of **Data over-fitting** , In your case ID3 algorithm is facing the issue of data over-fitting. This is the problem of Decision trees ,that it **splits the data until it make pure sets**. This Problem of Data over-fitting is fixed in it's extension that is **J48 by using Pruning**.

Another point to cover : You should use **K-fold Cross validation** for Validating your Model.